# Subselect Column with Sum

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

[image]

And I have this query:

```
Select StartDate, SubscriptionGUID,
(Select sum(TotalExistingDBHoursInPeriod) 
from dbo.SQLDBBusinessKPIDB_Snap  
where [Platform] = 'SAWA') as "SAWA Contrib"
FROM dbo.SQLDBBusinessKPIDB_Snap
```

Which is returning these results:
[image]

What I want is the "SAWA Contrib" to only be the sum for the row for the `SubscriptionGUID`, it is currently returning the total for all rows where the `[Platform] = "SAWA"`

Any pointers would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add constraint to inner query like:

```
Select so.StartDate, so.SubscriptionGUID,
(Select sum(TotalExistingDBHoursInPeriod) 
from dbo.SQLDBBusinessKPIDB_Snap si
where si.[Platform] = 'SAWA' and si.SubscriptionGUID = so.SubscriptionGUID) as "SAWA Contrib"
FROM dbo.SQLDBBusinessKPIDB_Snap so
```